# How to change value of field in FOSRestBundle/JMS Serializer?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have the field "image" in entities. But depends of action I want to show not original image, but image's preview (which I make in LiipImagineBundle). The one solution which I can imagine:

```
public function cgetAction(Request $request)
{
    $events = $this->container->get('gc.event_manager')->getEvents();
    foreach ($events as &$event) {
        $previewURL = $this->getPreview($event->getPhoto());
        $event->setPhoto($previewURL);
    }
    $event = false;

    return array(
        'events' => $events,
    );
}
```

But I don't like it, because if an entity has deep children's entities the code will be very  confusing.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 7):

Common problem when you want to return absolute url through API while using LiipImagine and FOSRest

Change EE\TYSBundle to your own, code taken from https://github.com/EE/TellYourStoryBundle/tree/develop

**JMSSerializer Handler Service with injected Cache Manager to get correct prefix**

```
ee_tys.serializer.filename_handler:
    class: EE\TYSBundle\Handler\FilenameHandler
    arguments:
        - "@liip_imagine.cache.manager"
    tags:
        - { name: 'jms_serializer.handler', type: Filename, format: json}
```

Handler for custom Filename type

**EE\TYSBundle\Handler\FilenameHandler.php**

```
<?php

namespace EE\TYSBundle\Handler;

use EE\TYSBundle\Entity\Filename;
use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;
use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\VisitorInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager;

class FilenameHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{

    function __construct(CacheManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }


    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'Filename',
                'method' => 'serializeFilenameToJson',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function serializeFilenameToJson(VisitorInterface $visitor, Filename $filename, array $type)
    {
        // `tile` is a name of Imagine filter you want to apply
        return $this->manager->getBrowserPath($filename, 'tile', true);
    }
}
```

**EE\TYSBundle\Entity\Filename**

```
<?php

namespace EE\TYSBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Class Filename
 * @package EE\TYSBundle\Entity
 */
class Filename {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $extension;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $parts = explode(".", $filename);

        $this->setName($parts[0]);

        $this->setExtension($parts[1]);

    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $extension
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setExtension($extension)
    {
        $this->extension = $extension;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getExtension()
    {
        return $this->extension;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     * @return Filename
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string filename
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return join(".", array($this->name, $this->extension));
    }

}
```

**usage of custom Filename type**

```
/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="background_filename", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Type("Filename")
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("background_uri")
 */
private $backgroundFilename;
```

From now on you will get background_uri with absolute url to your preview Image

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to define [Handler](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers).

> Handlers allow you to change the serialization, or deserialization
>   process for a single type/format combination.

Something like

```
class ImageHandler
{
    public function serialize(VisitorInterface $visitor, \FQCN\Image $image, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        // do some stuff

        return ...;
    }
}
```

And register it in `services.yml`

```
serializer.handler.image_handler:
    class: FQCN\Handler\ImageHandler
    arguments: []
    tags:
        - { name: "jms_serializer.handler", type: FQCN\AdvertImage, format: json, method: serialize }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question well, you need change value for correct before serialisation, i think manual can help [@Accessor](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor)

```
class User
{
    private $id;

    /** @Accessor(getter="getTrimmedName",setter="setName") */
    private $name;

    // ...
    public function getTrimmedName()
    {
        return trim($this->name);
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```